# How to run a Python file on button click in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having a Python page named **Home.py** and it is containing a button named **View Reports**. When I click this button I want another Python page named **Reports.py** to get executed. I developed the UI using tkinter.

Comment: You can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute the external script.  Or if the main block is inside a function in the external script, import the function and call the function.

Comment: I have tried the subprocess . But it wont work in my system.

Comment: What have you tried with `subprocess`?  Post the test code.

Comment: command = ("View Reports.py")
    subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)

Comment: Why didn't you use `python` to execute the `Reports.py` script?

Comment: But I want the script to get executed on the button click !!!

Comment: I mean the command: should it be `command="python Reports.py"`?

Comment: tried that also and didn't work

Comment: What `didn't work` means?  Any errors shown?  Try running your main script in a console and see whether there are errors reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. Works for me.

```
def RunWrapper():
    wrapper = ['python', 'Reports.py']
    result1 = subprocess.Popen(wrapper,  stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out1, err1 = result1.communicate()
    status_wrapper=out1.decode("utf-8")
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Execution of script is done")

Button.configure(pady="0",text='''Execute''',command=RunWrapper)
```